# How do I find declarations/definitions without an IDE?

Tags: c, gcc, ide, declaration

I've been using the Eclipse IDE for a few years now. When programming in C I'm used to Ctrl+Click on a symbol and Eclipse takes me to the file and line of the symbol's declaration.

Without an IDE, how do I achieve this? I'm using gcc to compile a massive FOSS project with hundreds of header files. Looking though the C files, I see functions that I would like to know more about. Finding the header file that declares said function is a tedious and manual task. Not to mention manual interpretation of macros...

GCC compiles the project and knows what the declarations are and where. Is it possible to generate a human readable index of all symbol declarations along with their filename and position for a given compilation?

Comment: [Ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags), [CScope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What are you using now, to "Looking though the C files ..." ?

Comment: @terencehill Lightweight text editors, nano, gedit, ect.

Comment: Is something like `find . -type f -name "*.h" | xargs grep [functionName]` not feasible for this?

Comment: @JETM oh this works really well.

Comment: Also, I would like to say this out loud. Wikipedia did a study and found that the most trusted and loyal editors were actually doing little things such as grammar edits and spelling. Meanwhile the unverified and untrusted individuals are more likely to add large portions of data to pages. I see the same on SO. High reputation users often go around and add small comments and correct english such as @EugeneSh. These comments are very useful and deserve to be answers. Future readers may miss this detail found in the comments. **TL;DR: Please stop putting answers in the comments.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the `-aux-info` flag; it will write a list of all functions declared or defined in a translation unit (including those in header files) to a specified output file.

Here's a dumb piece of code I wrote for another SO question (don't remember what it was for):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )
{
  const unsigned long long lim = 2000000;
  unsigned long long nums2lim[lim];

  printf( "%zu\n", sizeof nums2lim );
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with

```
gcc -o test -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -aux-info=test.aux test.c
```

yields this output in `test.aux`:

```
/* compiled from: . */
/* /usr/include/libio.h:413:NC */ extern int __underflow (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:414:NC */ extern int __uflow (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:415:NC */ extern int __overflow (_IO_FILE *, int);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:416:NC */ extern wint_t __wunderflow (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:417:NC */ extern wint_t __wuflow (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:418:NC */ extern wint_t __woverflow (_IO_FILE *, wint_t);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:451:NC */ extern int _IO_getc (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:452:NC */ extern int _IO_putc (int, _IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:453:NC */ extern int _IO_feof (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:454:NC */ extern int _IO_ferror (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:456:NC */ extern int _IO_peekc_locked (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:462:NC */ extern void _IO_flockfile (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:463:NC */ extern void _IO_funlockfile (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:464:NC */ extern int _IO_ftrylockfile (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:482:NC */ extern int _IO_vfscanf (_IO_FILE *, const char *, __va_list_tag *, int *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:484:NC */ extern int _IO_vfprintf (_IO_FILE *, const char *, __va_list_tag *);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:485:NC */ extern __ssize_t _IO_padn (_IO_FILE *, int, __ssize_t);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:486:NC */ extern size_t _IO_sgetn (_IO_FILE *, void *, size_t);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:488:NC */ extern __off64_t _IO_seekoff (_IO_FILE *, __off64_t, int, int);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:489:NC */ extern __off64_t _IO_seekpos (_IO_FILE *, __off64_t, int);
/* /usr/include/libio.h:491:NC */ extern void _IO_free_backup_area (_IO_FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:154:NC */ extern int remove (const char *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:156:NC */ extern int rename (const char *, const char *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:171:NC */ extern FILE *tmpfile (void);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:185:NC */ extern char *tmpnam (char *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:213:NC */ extern int fclose (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:218:NC */ extern int fflush (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:249:NC */ extern FILE *fopen (const char *, const char *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:256:NC */ extern FILE *freopen (const char *, const char *, FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:309:NC */ extern void setbuf (FILE *, char *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:314:NC */ extern int setvbuf (FILE *, char *, int, size_t);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:334:NC */ extern int fprintf (FILE *, const char *, ...);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:339:NC */ extern int printf (const char *, ...);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:342:NC */ extern int sprintf (char *, const char *, ...);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:349:NC */ extern int vfprintf (FILE *, const char *, __va_list_tag *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:354:NC */ extern int vprintf (const char *, __va_list_tag *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:357:NC */ extern int vsprintf (char *, const char *, __va_list_tag *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:365:NC */ extern int snprintf (char *, size_t, const char *, ...);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:369:NC */ extern int vsnprintf (char *, size_t, const char *, __va_list_tag *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:406:NC */ extern int fscanf (FILE *, const char *, ...);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:411:NC */ extern int scanf (const char *, ...);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:414:NC */ extern int sscanf (const char *, const char *, ...);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:425:NC */ extern int vfscanf (FILE *, const char *, __va_list_tag *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:432:NC */ extern int vscanf (const char *, __va_list_tag *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:437:NC */ extern int vsscanf (const char *, const char *, __va_list_tag *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:447:NC */ extern int fgetc (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:448:NC */ extern int getc (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:454:NC */ extern int getchar (void);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:489:NC */ extern int fputc (int, FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:490:NC */ extern int putc (int, FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:496:NC */ extern int putchar (int);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:539:NC */ extern char *fgets (char *, int, FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:546:NC */ extern char *gets (char *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:596:NC */ extern int fputs (const char *, FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:602:NC */ extern int puts (const char *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:609:NC */ extern int ungetc (int, FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:617:NC */ extern size_t fread (void *, size_t, size_t, FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:623:NC */ extern size_t fwrite (const void *, size_t, size_t, FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:656:NC */ extern int fseek (FILE *, long int, int);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:661:NC */ extern long int ftell (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:666:NC */ extern void rewind (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:705:NC */ extern int fgetpos (FILE *, fpos_t *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:710:NC */ extern int fsetpos (FILE *, const fpos_t *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:733:NC */ extern void clearerr (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:735:NC */ extern int feof (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:737:NC */ extern int ferror (FILE *);
/* /usr/include/stdio.h:753:NC */ extern void perror (const char *);
/* test.c:4:NF */ extern int main (int argc, const char **argv); /* (argc, argv) int argc; const char **argv; */
```

This flag only works for C code, though - it won't give you anything for C++.

Comment: If there was a phrase more precise than "this is exactly what I was looking for", I'd use it.

Comment: Weird how g++ does not have an equivalent... whatever C reigns superior once more.

Answer (score 1):

A light-weight, hackish approach would be to grep through the header files for the function name. Linux syntax would be something like:

`find . -type f -name "*.h" | xargs grep [functionName]`

It's what I use for my moderately-sized projects. I can't speak to how well it would scale.